# OpenGL ES IOS glCreateProgram() failure

Tags: ios, xcode, opengl-es, shader, objective-c++

I am currently creating an objective-c++ IOS OpenGL ES 3.0 3D game engine, but when I try to load shaders, `glCreateProgram()` returns `0`.
I am using `#include <OpenGLES/ES3/gl.h>` as my OpenGL base.

Here is my code:

```
m_program = glCreateProgram(); //ERROR

if (m_program == 0) 
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Error creating shader program\n"); //Catches ERROR
    exit(1);
}

std::string vertexShaderText = LoadShader(fileName + ".vs"); //Returns file contents.
std::string fragmentShaderText = LoadShader(fileName + ".fs"); //Returns file contents.

AddVertexShader(vertexShaderText); //Creates and attaches shader to program
AddFragmentShader(fragmentShaderText); //Creates and attaches shader to program

AddAllAttributes(vertexShaderText); //Identifies all attributes in shader and adds them.

CompileShader(); //Compile the program, link the program and use the program

AddShaderUniforms(vertexShaderText); //Identifies all uniforms and adds them.
AddShaderUniforms(fragmentShaderText); //Identifies all uniforms and adds them.
```

Comment: Call `glGetError()` after you call `glCreateProgram()` to get a better idea what's up. (Or better yet, don't pepper your code with `glGetError` calls and instead create an OpenGL ES Error breakpoint in Xcode. Maybe even have that breakpoint do a frame capture so you can see everything that's going on in your GL context at the time of the error.) Otherwise there's not much to go on here, but my guess is you don't have a current `EAGLContext` at the time you try to create the program.

Comment: @rickster Yep, turns out I somehow managed to call glCreateProgram() before i setup the EAGLContext. Thanks you saved me!!!